# How to get oh my zsh in Amazon2 wsl terminal in vscode?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zsh, wsl2, oh-my-zsh

I should preface this with I am a longtime macOS user so I am sorry in advance if I ask a dumb question here.

My team at work uses Amazon workspace and there is a version of wsl we use for our terminals. Essentially so far it feels like Linux/Unix save for the ugly and non highlighted interface. see screenshot.

[image]

That screenshot is from vscode. What I'd like is to get all that good stuff I'm used to i.e. current branch, syntax highlighting. via zsh!

I found a way to get it on ubuntu, but can't get it to work on vscode. Can anyone help with this?

**Update**
To be clear wsl works in my shell in vscode but I can't get oh-my-zsh to work there. Is there a way to add that shell to vscode, when running Amazon2/wsl?

Comment: Your VSCode terminal appears to be running WSL/Ubuntu as the root user.  When you start `wsl` from PowerShell, is `root` the user there?  When you say you, *"found a way to get it on ubuntu"*, can you elaborate?  What you did there might not be the correct way to do it.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi yes when I enter `wsl` it boots up like in vscode.

Comment: So again, need to understand what *you* do to get it to work in Ubuntu.  Then we can change or fix that to hopefully have it work correctly in VSCode.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that I followed this [guide](https://kheohyeewei.medium.com/level-up-your-vscode-terminal-to-oh-my-zsh-shell-on-windows-10-d3e067179b50)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still confused - The directions you followed say to start WSL by using the `wsl` command.  And you say that using those instructions, you got it working.  But here in the comments you say that when you type `wsl` it is *not* working (appearing like it is in VSCode).  It sounds like you are still saying two different things!  :-).  Please edit your question to show exactly what commands you are using when it works as you expect, and what commands you are using when it doesn't work - Thanks!

Comment: WSL works in vscode, but I can't get oh-my-zsh framework in there. Or is there a way to augment wsl to utilize themes, color syntaxing?